# Counting number of operations in Python

Tags: python-3.x, linear-algebra

What I am doing wrong in the following code:

```
import dis


def count_operations(f):
    operations = 0
    for op in dis.get_instructions(f):
        if op.opname in ('ADD', 'SUB', 'MULT', 'DIV', 'MOD'):
            operations += 1
    return operations

def solve_system(A, b):
    x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
    return x

A = np.array([[2, 3],
              [3, 4]])
b = np.array([8, 11])

operations = count_operations(solve_system)

print(f'Number of operations: {operations}')
```

I wrote two functions, one for counting operations and one for solving a system.

Comment: [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? See also: [ask].

Comment: Why do you think you are doing something wrong in the code?

Comment: `dis` doesn't do "deep" searches in any functions afaik. All `count_operations` is doing is checking what the function itself is doing, not what child calls made are doing. If you look at its output for `count_operations(solve_system)`, there are likely just some calls to `LOAD_FAST` and `CALL_FUNCTION`.

Comment: when I run this code, I got zero operations as an answer which is not true. So something is wrong.

Comment: so how I can fix this to get the number of operations printed?

Comment: You likely can't do what you're trying to do. Afaik, numpy offloads thee actual work to C code, and `dis` won't show non-Python disassembly. You would need to look at the native bytecode making up the numpy library.

Comment: You can also run `dis.dis(solve_system)` to see the output of the disassembler. On Python's side, all it does is loading `np.linalg.solve` method, and offload the actual computation to the lower-level C code in `numpy`. You won't be able to peek into `numpy` code from Python itself, because to `numpy`, Python is just an API server.

Comment: Why do you think there would be any 'ADD', 'SUB', 'MULT', 'DIV', 'MOD' operations performed by `solve_system`?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy does a lot of the heavy lifting with (compiled) library routines written in C or Fortran. You won't see those in `dis` output:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import dis

In [3]: def solve_system(A, b):
   ...:     x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
   ...:     return x
   ...:     

In [4]: dis.dis(solve_system)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (np)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (linalg)
              4 LOAD_METHOD              2 (solve)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             10 CALL_METHOD              2
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (x)

  3          14 LOAD_FAST                2 (x)
             16 RETURN_VALUE

In [5]: dis.dis(np.linalg.solve)
179           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (dispatcher)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (args)
              4 BUILD_MAP                0
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (kwargs)
              8 DICT_MERGE               1
             10 CALL_FUNCTION_EX         1
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (relevant_args)

180          14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (implement_array_function)

181          16 LOAD_DEREF               1 (implementation)
             18 LOAD_DEREF               2 (public_api)
             20 LOAD_FAST                2 (relevant_args)
             22 LOAD_FAST                0 (args)
             24 LOAD_FAST                1 (kwargs)

180          26 CALL_FUNCTION            5
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

From the `numpy.linalg.solve` documentation:

> The solutions are computed using LAPACK routine `_gesv`.

Those routines (`sgesv` and `dgesv` for single and double precision) are written in Fortran.
See e.g. the [documentation for dgesv](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html).

Answer (score -1):

This is actually an interesting question. So you are making a wrapper function to show the amount of operations that are in a given tuple.

On inspection, the `if` statement is failing and you can verify this by including an `else`.

So i do this modification to verify:

```py
import dis
import numpy as np

def count_operations(f):
    operations = 0
    not_operations = 0    # <---added this
    for op in dis.get_instructions(f):
        if op.opname in ('ADD', 'SUB', 'MULT', 'DIV', 'MOD'):
            operations += 1
        else:
            not_operations += 1
    return operations, not_operations

def solve_system(A, b):
    x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
    return x

A = np.array([[2, 3],
              [3, 4]])
b = np.array([8, 11])

operations = count_operations(solve_system)

print(f'Number of operations: {operations}')
```

The above code now returns a `operations` as a tuple (of ops and not ops).

When i run the modified code i get this:

```
Number of operations: (0, 9)
```

You can also add a print statement to expose what you get in each loop. An example of the first operation in the list is this:

```
Instruction(opname='LOAD_GLOBAL', opcode=116, arg=0, argval='np', argrepr='np', offset=0, starts_line=18, is_jump_target=False)
```

Which is `<class 'dis.Instruction'>`
So you could expose that...

Finally, i can show that the code does infact work, but adding `LOAD_FAST` into the tuple which then returns `(3,6)` as it occurs 3 times...